# key strokes take a long time to register, ubuntu 16.04, ubuntu 18.04, etc

Tags: 18.04, keyboard, malware

No matter what Ubuntu version or kernel version, some time after install it comes to the point where keystrokes take a long time to register.  Sometimes it misses a character or duplicates a character, but mostly it just takes a long time for anything to register.  This is sporadic.  It may work OK for a while and then have the problem for a while.  I have new batteries in the keyboard and it is not related to my USB hardware because it happens on any computer here in my home.  I might try to use a wired keyboard just to see if the problem exists with it.

I'm writing this on a Ubuntu 18.04 (bionic)system with all current updates and using kernel 4.15.0-192-generic (#203-Ubuntu SMP Wed Aug 10 17:40:03 UTC 2022).  It is a wireless keyboard thru USB.

Could I possibly always pick up some sort of malware as a result of my software choices and web habits?  Is there a malware scanner I can use to check for such malware? How can I determine the root cause and then fix it?

Comment: Is it possibly related to the *keyboard itself*? that sounds like the keyboard is broken. Try another keyboard, see if you have the same issue. Possibly also wireless interference with the bluetooth connection, do you have a microwave or other device that emits radio waves nearby? Anyways, try another wired keyboard. And "happens on any computer" makes it sound *even more* like an issue with the keyboard rather than the OS.

Comment: Does it go away when you turn off the power of your keyboard(!) and turn it on again? Or unplug the USB dongle and replug it? Please also try a different keyboard with a different USB dongle - wired or wireless doesn't matter in the first place, but wired would be better for the test. For me it sounds like broken keyboard hardware as well - but maybe also just the USB dongle, so I would always switch both.

Comment: I don't have a wired keyboard right now, but I'm going to get one and see if that helps.

Comment: @cyberbrain,  The problem comes and goes.  I don't see that power off/on or the re-inserting the USB dongle helps.  I still need to find a wired keyboard to test.  If there is no problem with the wired keyboard I'll rule out malware and conclude the problem is in  the USB system somewhere or the keyboard itself.  It is an ASUS B350 mobo with AMD A10-9700 RADEON R7, 10 COMPUTE CORES 4C+6G. The keyboard is Logitech MK320. When I started this comment it worked OK, but now the problem is here.

Comment: If you think it's malware, you have to act NOW. You could order a keyboard (e.g. from Amazon), test it, and if that fails also, you just return it as failing. Cheapest keyboards are around 10€ and below.